# Curious issue in Delphi using Stream reader

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

So I have a binary file and I am reading a word value which is 2 bytes the value is an Int16 = 43140, however whenever I read it in Delphi it returns as 43104, I wrote the code to read it in C# just to test and it reads correctly it is only in Delphi it is reading incorrectly, it looks like the 0 and 4 are shifting places for some reason.

```
  TMyHeader= packed record
     Value1       :String[20];
     Value2       :Word; // Is 43140 but reading as 43104
     Value3       :Word;
     Value4       :Word; // Is 43140 but reading as 43104
  end;

FileRead (fhandle, header, sizeof(MyHeader));
```

Comment: Possibly, you have UTF-16 characters in source file. Instead of ANSI.

Comment: An [mcve] that demonstrates the issue would be helpful. It's impossible to guess what might be wrong. Your code also does  not use Stream reader. What question are you actually asking?

Comment: Let me knock one together, I have used both Stream reader and FileRead from SysUtils and both give the same result.

Comment: Strange, when I built this small example it works fine, I think there must be something else causing it then, I will need to dig more...

Comment: Do your digging before asking unanswerable questions. A question like this needs a [mcve].

Comment: How do you check Delphi reads wrong and C# reads right? Maybe it is the opposite ? Maybe it is C# that reads it wrong not Delphi ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not use *Stream reader*, and it's entirely unlikely that the issue is with reading the file. Here's an example of using `TFileStream` to both read and write your record successfully without altering the values in any way. (Clearly you'll have to change the `TestFile` constant to point to a valid, writable location on your system first.)

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, Classes;

type
  TMyHeader = packed record
    Value1: String[20];
    Value2: Word;
    Value3: Word;
    Value4: Word;
  end;

var
  MyHeader: TMyHeader;
  Stream: TFileStream;

const
  TestFile = 'E:\TempFiles\Testheader.bin';

begin
  // Initialize the record
  MyHeader.Value1 := 'Testing One Two';
  MyHeader.Value2 := 43140;
  MyHeader.Value3 := 12345;
  MyHeader.Value4 := 43140;

  // Show what it contains. The `[]` brackets are to clearly delimit Value1
  WriteLn(Format('Before write: [%s] %d %d %d', 
                  [MyHeader.Value1, MyHeader.Value2, MyHeader.Value3, MyHeader.Value4]));

  // Write it to the stream.
  Stream := TFileStream.Create(TestFile, fmCreate, fmShareDenyNone);
  try
    Stream.Write(MyHeader, SizeOf(TMyHeader));
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;

  // Clear the contents of MyHeader before reading back, and show the empty values
  FillChar(MyHeader, SizeOf(TMyHeader), 0);
  WriteLn(Format('Before read: [%s] %d %d %d', 
                 [MyHeader.Value1, MyHeader.Value2, MyHeader.Value3, MyHeader.Value4]));
  Stream := TFileStream.Create(TestFile, fmOpenRead, fmShareDenyNone);
  try
    Stream.Read(MyHeader, SizeOf(TMyHeader));
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
  // Output what we've read back in to verify it is correct
  WriteLn(Format('After read: [%s] %d %d %d', 
                 [MyHeader.Value1, MyHeader.Value2, MyHeader.Value3, MyHeader.Value4]));
  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: I found the problem, there was an error in the header, 1 byte off, seems to work now.